# how to test java applets with html?

Tags: java, html, applet

I need a test server to upload html files with java applets. I was told to try to set up apache but i cannot find an executable from the official download page (http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi). Is there another ways to have a test server ? I've read that html pages containing applets can be opened from the local file system without having to use apache but since i'm really new to networking i don't know how to do this.

Comment: You don't need a webserver to test an applet. Either use a viewer or embedd the applet in an HTML file that you store on your computer.

Comment: Control Panel > Java > Advanced > Java Console (Show Console) and check what is the error its throwing while loading. Important your applet should be signed with code signing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Use applet viewer. Then you don't need to worry about servers nor creating HTML pages.

Comment: I tried to use the command appletviewer from console after excecuting the java file, i have "I/O exception while reading ..the file". When excecuted  the java file from console i had "Note : .java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."  "Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.". I guess i can edit in the code if it's needed

Answer (score 0):

Some important points on this for applet development/testing

1. Applet should be signed with a valid code signing certificate
2. You should have latest JRE.
   NOTE: Chrome and other browsers are doing away with NPAPI plugins, so jre plugins may not be there. So you cannot run on Chrome. Although there is as workaround with which you can enable JRE plugin explicitly.
3. Load applet in html page as below..`<applet id="any id" width="80" height="80" code="com.abc.def.class" archive="applet.jar" codebase="/path/appletfolder/">`

   Note: applet tag is deprecated in html5. Use embed or object instead.